# Фильтр checkbox из json

Tags: json, reactjs

Фильтр на reactjs должен выполнять выборку из json файла.
Например,

```
{sex: "male", name: "John"},{sex: "female", name: "Kate"}
```

Визуально 3 checkbox: All, Male, Female. По checked выводится информация.

Есть у кого-нибудь ссылки на подобные примеры? Не обязательно готовое решение.

Comment: какое отношение данный вопрос имеет к реакту? Чем создание фильтра для реакта будет отличатся от фильтра для angular или js? И это не вопрос, тз для фриланса.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вряд ли есть конкретно такой пример, проще написать самому. Компонент мог бы выглядеть, например, так:

```js
import React, {Component} from 'react';


export default class Filter extends Component {
    constructor(props, context) {
        super(props, context);

        this.state = {
            types: {
                male: false,
                female: false
            }
        }
    }

    onCheckboxChange(type) {
        this.setState({
            types: {
                ...this.state.types,
                [type]: !this.state.types[type]
            }
        });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <input id="chk-male"
                               type="checkbox"
                               value={this.state.types.male}
                               onChange={this.onCheckboxChange.bind(this, "male")}
                        /><label htmlFor="chk-male">Male</label>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <input id="chk-female"
                               type="checkbox"
                               value={this.state.types.female}
                               onChange={this.onCheckboxChange.bind(this, "female")}
                        /><label htmlFor="chk-female">Female</label>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <div>
                    {this.props.json.filter(item => this.state.types[item.sex]).map(item => (
                        <div>{item.name}</div>
                    ))}
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

И вызывать его так:

```js
<Filter json={[{sex: "male", name: "John"},{sex: "female", name: "Kate"}]} />
```

Comment: молодец! сделали за кого-то работу за бесплатно.

Comment: Здесь работы на 5-10 минут, вполне подойдет в качестве мануала.

Comment: дело не в времени а в создании ауры ресурса. Если делать домашнии задания за участников, отвечать на вопросы на которые ответы даны в книгах для начинающих, то ресурс превратится в ответы мейлру. Если Вы хотите общаться с профессионалами на профессиональные темы, то не нужно на мой взгляд поощрять подобные вопросы, да ещё сомнительного содержания. Разве не видите что вопрос был задан профессиональным задавальщиком уровень которого бы не позволил спрашивать такую ерунду.

Comment: но я сказанул немного лишнего и кажется что я призываю к чему-то. нет, я хочу лишь правильный ресурс с правильными вопросами, которые помогают развиваться, а не детский сад, который отнимает время.

Comment: спасибо Роман, именно как мануал и сгодился. Переделал код под свое условие.